# Phonon Angular Momentum

Tags: phonons, phonopy

Can anyone help me understand what is Phonon Angular Momentum? How does it affect thermal properties? Any relevant books and papers are welcome, if you have suggestions.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago. I started working on an answer to this many months ago, but it would take long time for me to find that old browser tab. Let me know if you need an answer urgently or perhaps put a bounty on it and I can spend the time to go and find what I started, and finish writing an answer.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thank you so much for your time and effort. I don't need it urgently as of now, I am in learning phase and this topic is part of it. Eventually I will need it. I am searching too, but it will take time. Maybe one day I will get it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you need it later, then let me know. I did work on an answer many months ago.